# Stack divs without giving a z-index

Tags: html, css

I want to overlap multiple `tile` divs over each other using margin-right: -10px.

I want the previous div to appear on top and new sibling divs after it. As it is, the previous div will be overlapped by the newer div. This can be easily solved by using `float: right` on the `tile` element and reversing the order.

But this solution is breaking another requirement I have. Which is, selecting the first `same` class after a `another` class.

```
.another + .same {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Is there a way to overlap the div as it is without using position absolute or a z-index. These tiles are dynamically added so adding a z-index means I would have to do it with javascript which I would like to avoid.

```css
.tile {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b {
  background-color: pink;
}

.c {
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.d {
  background-color: grey;
}

.containerA {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.containerB {
  width: 150px;
}

.containerB .tile {
  float: right;
}

.another + .same {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerA">
<div>
Normal
</div>
  <div class="tile a another">
  </div>
  <div class="tile b another">
  </div>
  <div class="tile c same">
  </div>
  <div class="tile d same">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="containerB">
<div>
Expected outcome with float right but sibling selector broken
</div>
  <div class="tile d same">
  </div>
  <div class="tile c same">
  </div>
  <div class="tile b another">
  </div>
  <div class="tile a another">
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/be51xxku/2/

Comment: don't think it can be done without z-index as you will always need it to be the opposite way for your stacking context and because of that, you cannot do a previous sibling selector

Comment: Are u using SASS or LESS? In that case you can perhaps set the zindex using the nth child property.

Comment: @rach8garg I'm using SASS

Comment: See...if you can generate values of zindex based in nth child (n*10) your divs can have increasing order of zindex. Even in simple CSS if nth child works for coloring table rows striped ( even odd ) then it must be possible for other elements too.

Comment: @rach8garg I don't have a fixed number of elements. Tiles can be added or removed, so they change in number and sometimes in order.

Comment: You can use loops in SASS. Run it over n values (30 say) and predefine the z-index for the divs in sequence. So first div will have 10 (1*10) and element 50 will have (50*10) zindex. You just need the max value of n.

Comment: Will you have any text content in the container div?

Comment: @user3607282 why are you writing elements in reverse order in second option....is this is a requirement..?

Comment: @Pete I'm caught in a dilemma, I have to either use javascript to manage adding / removing and maintaining z-indexs to tiles that get added / removed / their order changed ect. Or I have to use javascript to always find the latest element which is the last element with the class `same` and add a `last` class. And that latest element can change, which means I have to listen to changes. :(

Comment: @Bhuwan Yes, the order needs to be the same as how it appears without using float: right

Comment: _“tiles that get added / removed / their order changed”_ - well how does that happen in the first place? Isn’t JS involved in that process already? Looping through all elements in current DOM order and decreasing the z-index while doing so would be rather trivial, and should be negligible regarding performance, so if you could just trigger that after _any_ kind of change to your element list you’d be done ...

Comment: How are the classes decided / added, if you do this server side couldn't you do some sort of forward lookup to see if the next element has a class of another and then apply a class of border to the current element?  That way you would be able to do your float right technique

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to change the CSS of your element to create this effect visually.

Here is an example where I used radial-gradient instead of background-color. I also used variable to make it easy to handle:

```css
:root {
  --back-color: #fff;
}

.tile {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: -15px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at left, transparent 15px, var(--back-color) 16px);
}

.a {
  background: yellow
}

.b {
  --back-color: pink;
}

.c {
  --back-color: turquoise;
}

.d {
  --back-color: grey;
}

.containerA {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.containerB {
  width: 150px;
}

.containerB .tile {
  float: right;
}

.another+.same {
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerA">
  <div>
    Normal
  </div>
  <div class="tile a another">
  </div>
  <div class="tile b another">
  </div>
  <div class="tile c same">
  </div>
  <div class="tile d same">
  </div>
</div>
```